# Selenium webdriver throws Internal server error

Tags: selenium, server, webdriver, internals

In a web application, the browser launched from selenium webdriver throws internal server error.
Manually opening the same web application works fine.
I tried to delete the cookie in the browser launched from driver when I got error and once cookie is cleared and refreshed, I am able to get the application.
I have tried driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() which dint work.
Any suggestions for me please?

Comment: you have the webiste url ?

Comment: Have you tried to run WebDriver with your profile data? Is an url correct in the browser started by WebDriver? App opened manually in incognito mode works fine?